# How do I iterate over a list in a hash in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, hash

I want to get the elements of the array SIZE from the A_TABLE, just like it shows in the top part below, but with an iterator, as I totally failed to do in the bottom part. 
New to Python about one hour ago, and I'll keep looking, but any suggestions appreciated.

```
SIZE   = ('too small', 'just right', 'too large')

A_TABLE = {}
A_TABLE['size'] = SIZE
print "size is " + A_TABLE['size'][0]
print "size is " + A_TABLE['size'][1]
print "size is " + A_TABLE['size'][2]

for x in A_TABLE['size'][x]:
    print "size is " + A_TABLE['size'][x]
```

Comment: Your `print` statements show that you are using python2.  If you are "new to python," you should be learning python3, not python2.  Python2 is rapidly approaching [end of life](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: % python --version
Python 2.7.6.Thanks. I will sort that out directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping in the wrong way, here's how you should do it:

```
SIZE = ('too small', 'just right', 'too large')

A_TABLE = {}
A_TABLE['size'] = SIZE

for x in A_TABLE['size']: # change here
    print "size is " + x  # and here
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Waiting '7 minutes' to accept answer.